# New Sidemenu irregularity

Tags: codenameone

My sideMenuOnTop gives me an out of place sidemenu panel as shown in the attached image. Something strange tho. When I click on the search icon to perform a search and cancel, the sidemnu now appears to be normal except that the "DataPlat Collector" bit is not visible. What could I be doing wrong.

I already delcared global toolbar and sidemenuontop flag to true.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I follow? Do you mean the gap on top? This was fixed recently in git and will be a part of the coming library update this Friday